# Lucene.Net.Replicator how to use sample example

Tags: c#, lucene.net

is there any way to replicate lucene.net indexes?  I found this package in **nuget** "**Lucene.Net.Replicator** -Version 4.8.0-beta00005 ". It seems it will work with Lucene.Net 4.8. But I don't have idea on how to use.

Comment: Hi,

Personally I don't use the replicator framework, let me ask you a question before I can help you any further: is your index static? or do you constantly delete documents?

Comment: my index doesn't have any delete or weekly once I do bulk delete, but it will have regular add and updates. I need this replication for performance(my wcf works with load balancer), fail-over and high-availability ( to have multiple indexes on 2 or more servers, so if one goes down, still indexed content will be available). I know there are other Solr, Elasticsearch etc.. are available, but would like have completely .net code. Just need replicatoin. @rojobo

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying bro, because I have the exact same thing myself (strictly .NET stack, & multiple servers)

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly I'm not at my desktop computer hang on

Answer (score 0):

I use Lucene.Net in a very similar application as described in your comment above (load balancer, multiple servers, fail-over, etc).

My solution for replication was to make a Windows Service application (I did not have to use the replication API) that will re-generate the index every so-often (it could be every hour, or every week). Once the index is generated it will copy it to all the servers and remove any old indexes (directory delete).

Then in my application I have a timer that will check to see if there is a new index available and update the IndexReader and IndexSearcher when one is found.

It works perfectly , Ive had no issues at all using it like this.

As far as adding new documents I use near-real time searching and it works really good too, you would just need to make sure your logic inside your application adjusts to what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to you handle NRT and index regeneration-distribution with a timer? I mean if a user lands on server A, he makes changes NRT on this index. If his next request lands on server B..? How do you handle this? I want also to maintain a strictly .Net stack here :)